# How to declare a type being a list of entries in Swagger

Tags: java, jax-rs, swagger

I'd like to "manually" declare a type of field being a list of entries in swagger.

Let's say I have totally custom

```
public class MyCustomList implements List<MyValue> {
....
}
```

Now I have a model class

```
@Data
public class MyModel {
    public MyCustomList problematicField;
}
```

I'd like to make Swagger to understand that `MyCustomList` is a list (array) of `MyValue`.

In `@ApiOperation` I'd set

```
@ApiOperation(value = "..", response = MyValue.class, responseContainer = "List")
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can accomplish this with a custom model converter.  See here:

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/overriding-models

For a guide on converting classes manually, but in short, it looks like such:

```
import com.wordnik.swagger.converter.*;

String jsonString = "{" +
"  \"id\": \"Date\"," +
"  \"properties\": {" +
"    \"value\": {" +
"      \"required\": true," +
"      \"description\": \"Date in ISO-8601 format\"," +
"      \"notes\": \"Add any notes you like here\"," +
"      \"type\": \"string\"," +
"      \"format\": \"date-time\"" +
"    }" +
"  }" +
"}";
OverrideConverter converter = new OverrideConverter();
converter.add("java.util.Date", jsonString);

ModelConverters.addConverter(converter, true);
```

Comment: Yeah, but this type does not have properties. It's a list of something.